# How can I count the number of elements which are distributed randomly in each region (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab

In my work, with MATLAB,i tried to distribute N points randomly in a circle. I divide this field in some regions (= i divided this circle into segments with angle alpha). So i like to count the number of elements in each regions.
Does anyone know please how to count the number of elements in each piece of pie??

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  Also, showing an image would help in illustrating your objective.  You don't have enough reputation points to post an image, so place a link on a public sharing website (dropbox, imgur, etc.) and I will update your post to embed this image for all of us to see.

Answer (score 2):

Use polar coordinates for your point, convert them with `[theta,roh] = cart2pol(X,Y)`.

Roh is the distrance from origin, use `A=(roh>2.7)+(roh>5.2)` to get a 0 for first radios, 1 for second and 2 for third. For `theta` it's the same trick. `B=(theta>pi/6)+(theta>pi/3)`

Now you can look for all points with `A==0&&B==0` to get the small segment next to the x-axis.